# I downloaded iTunes 10 but now it won't update my iPod Touch software

Tags: ipod-touch, itunes

I downloaded the newest version of iTunes because it said it couldn't update the iPod Touch to 4.2 without it, but after the download I went to update my iPod Touch and iTunes said it couldn't contact the update server. This happened when I downloaded iTunes 9 and tried to update, but I never fixed it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a error number associated with this error?

Did you check to see if you have an internet connection?

Did you restart your computer?

Did you wait a while and try back later? Apple could be experiencing a downtime when you tried to access their server.

Do you have a firewall on? Is the port open for iTunes?

It could be any number of things...Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Would be helpful in narrowing down the cause:

- Win or Mac OS X?
- Current version installed? (btw, the latest version is now 4.2.1. A last-minute fix caused the version number to revise)

Things that come to mind off-hand:

- iTunes version you downloaded is 10.1? (the latest at this moment)
- Firewall? Antivirus?

Worst case: Use the links [from this page](http://www.dkszone.net/download-ios-4-2-1-iphone-4-3gs-3g-ipod-touch-4g-3g-2g-ipad), or a page like this, to download the image for the new OS manually and perform a backup-and-restore using the image. WARNING: Not for novices!